Some random ownership changes through `rsync -a` inside a LXC container
I am migrating a dedicated server running Debian 12 with LXC and a couple of containers.
I use rsync with -avhze options from the new server (pulling), with root user on both sides.
It appears that inside a container, the owner and group have changed on 2 mysql folders :
Old server :
root@myOriginalContainer:/# ls /var/lib
drwx--S---  7 mysql   mysql 4,0K 10 juil. 18:10 mysql/
drwx------  2 mysql   mysql 4,0K  4 juin   2017 mysql-files/

New server :
root@myRsyncedContainer:/# ls /var/lib
drwx--S---  7 996   polkitd 4,0K 10 juil. 18:10 mysql/
drwx------  2 996   polkitd 4,0K  4 juin   2017 mysql-files/

I checked with less /etc/passwd that the users are identical in both copies of the container : same names and numerical ID's.
Edit2 : polkitd debian package may be the culprit, but I am not able to understand how.
Edit3 : OK, it is a LXC mapping issue. I need to look into this, any help appreciated!
So my questions are :

How is it possible ? And who's fault is that ? (rsync, mariadb less likely, other ?)
What is the good way to solve this ?
Which other files may be affected ? How could I check this "container-widely" if necessary ?

Thanks in advance for any tip!

I appreciate your effort to provide the relevant info, but there are several critical things missing. Are you running rsync on the old server (pushing to the new one) or on the new one (pulling from the old one)? What user account is rsync running as on the local and remote systems? What is the user and group IDs for mysqld on the old system and polkitd group on the new one? Also, checking the files with ls -ln (which will show numeric user and group IDs, rather than names) would probably help.

Thanks for your questions. I edited my post to clean up useless info and answer most of your questions :

rsync launched on the new server, pulling from the old one
root user on both sides
users, groups and numerical ID's are strictly the same on both sides (logical, as I rsync an LXC container)


The solution isn't completely satisfactory: I've just given up trying to figure out how to handle it with lxc, and chown the necessary folders inside the new container.
I'm still interested in a more consistent answer.
